# Convert a list with various vector length (Compressed Row Storage) into sparseMatrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, reshape

I use to store my sparse data in MariaDB table with [DynamicColumns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/) structure. 
When I am importing it to R I'm getting the following `db_frame` data frame:

```
db_frame <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "SELECT uid, column_json(groups) FROM matrix")
db_frame
  uid                      column_json(groups)
1   8              {"33755311":1,"58534882":1}
2   9                           {"75338985":1}
3  15               {"5445504":1,"58534882":1}
4  16 {"14897324":1,"22522055":1,"68471405":1}
5  20              {"22522055":1,"48940689":1}
```

My aim is to convert it from the above Compressed Row Storage to the following **sparse-format(!)** Matrix:

```
   14897324 22522055 33755311 48940689 5445504 58534882 68471405 75338985
8         .        .        1        .       .        1        .        .
9         .        .        .        .       .        .        .        1
15        .        .        .        .       1        1        .        .
16        1        1        .        .       .        .        1        .
20        .        1        .        1       .        .        .        .
```

I have done this in two ways but it seems to me both are very inefficient.
In real life number of variables (columns) is about **2-3K**, and number of observations (rows) ~ **1 million**. So my both methods take a very long time to finish the work (days).

Is there other, more elegant way to do this conversion?
Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** There are links to two dataframes in R format:

1. [db_frame](http://public.lovesecret.ru/temp/db_frame.Rda) - data frame from example 5 observations
2. [db_frame_10K](http://public.lovesecret.ru/temp/db_frame_10K.Rda) - real data frame with 10K observations for speed testing

**UPD2:** SPEED COMPARISON TABLE for convertion data frame with [10K observation](http://public.lovesecret.ru/temp/db_frame_10K.Rda)
*Core i3 2.93 Ghz*

```
Method1 My            162-188 sec
Method2 My             94-102 sec
Method3 @amatsuo_net    47-57 sec (but not exactly required format)
Method4 @amatsuo_net+My     6 sec
```

---

*For your information my two methods:*

The first step is to convert `db_frame` data frame to more friendly list to have a possibility to extract variables names for each observation from it.

```
library("rjson")
var_list <- lapply(db_frame[,-1],fromJSON)
var_list_names <- lapply(var_list,names)
var_list_names
[[1]]
[1] "33755311" "58534882"

[[2]]
[1] "75338985"

[[3]]
[1] "5445504"  "58534882"

[[4]]
[1] "14897324" "22522055" "68471405"

[[5]]
[1] "22522055" "48940689"
```

Lists of variables and observations names:

```
groups <- sort(unique(unlist(var_list_names)))
groups
[1] "14897324" "22522055" "33755311" "48940689" "5445504"  "58534882" "68471405" "75338985"
uids <- db_frame$uid
uids
[1] "8"  "9"  "15" "16" "20"
```

*------------- Method 1 using "for i" cycle*

```
row_number = length(uids)
col_number = length(groups)

# creating empty sparse matrix M1
M1 <- sparseMatrix(dims = c(row_number,col_number), i={}, j={}, x=1)
rownames(M1) <- uids
colnames(M1) <- groups

# filling M1
for (i in 1:row_number) {
      M1[i,var_list_names[[i]]] <-1
}
M1
```

*-------------- Method 2 using "reshape2"*

```
library("reshape2")
long <- melt(var_list)
long
   value       L2 L1
1      1 33755311  1
2      1 58534882  1
3      1 75338985  2
4      1  5445504  3
5      1 58534882  3
6      1 14897324  4
7      1 22522055  4
8      1 68471405  4
9      1 22522055  5
10     1 48940689  5

i=long$L1
j=match(long[,"L2"],groups)

M2 <-sparseMatrix(i=i, j=j, x=1)
rownames(M2) <- uids
colnames(M2) <- groups
M2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@amatsuo_net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6608798/amatsuo-net) who point me to `rbindlist` function from `data.table` package.
I have slightly simplified his code and added conversion to sparse format.
Conversion time on test 10K observation is impressive **6 sec**!

*-------------- Method 4 using "rbindlist"*

```
library(RMySQL)
library(Matrix)
library(rjson)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

df <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "SELECT uid, column_json(groups) FROM matrix")    

# "rbindlist" does all the work    
M3 <- lapply(df[,-1],fromJSON) %>% rbindlist(fill=TRUE)

# replace NA with 0 (required for sparsematrix type)
M3[is.na(M3)] <- 0 
# converting to sparsematrix type
M3 <- as(as.matrix(M3), "sparseMatrix")

# make some order :)
M3 <- M3[, order(as.integer(colnames(M3)))]
row.names(M3) <- df$uid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, but not sure how efficient it will be as I don't have the test data.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
split(df, seq(nrow(df))) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) {
    dt <- data.table(t(unlist(fromJSON(x$column_json))))
    dt[, id := x$uid]
  }) %>% 
  rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Close, but not exactly what is required. 
I have uploaded source data frame. You can check the result yourself. And other question - how to convert it to sparse format? Preferably in the begining because of lot memory cosumption.

Comment: You can also check your code efficiency in comparison table. (see UPD2)

Comment: Glad I helped (although it wasn't what exactly you needed) :)